# Step does not have matching glue code in cucumber feature file

Tags: cucumber-junit

Step does not have matching glue code even though the methods are defined correctly in Step Definition file using the snippets

Comment: where do you keep feature file, folder structure ? is it not under src/test/resources

Comment: How are you trying to run the feature files? What are your @CucumberOptions?